# remove embedded document from mongo db $pull is not working

Tags: mongodb

I have embedded document in mongodb how can I remove only one address where pincode : 140901 and update where pincode is : 152364

```
db.add_fun.insert({
"_id" : ObjectId("5a82e6dc1139b572569fa785"),
"name" : "Vikas",
"salary" : 72.0,
"address" : [ 
    {
        "address_id" : ObjectId("5a82f0e51139b572569fa78c"),
        "address" : "Mullanpur ",
        "pincode" : "140901",
        "country" : "India"
    }, 
    {
        "address_id" : ObjectId("5a82f0e51139b572569fa78d"),
        "address" : "mohali ",
        "pincode" : "152364",
        "country" : "India"
    }
]
})
```

I try this but not working

```
db.add_fun.update({},
        {
            $pull: {
                        address: {
                            $elemMatch: {
                                pincode: "140901"
                            }
                        }
            }
        },
        {
            multi:true
        }
    )
```

want to remove this

```
{
"address_id" : ObjectId("5a82f0e51139b572569fa78c"),
"address" : "Mullanpur ",
"pincode" : "140901",
"country" : "India"
},
```

and want this result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a82e6dc1139b572569fa785"),
    "name" : "Vikas",
    "salary" : 72.0,
    "address" : [ 

        {
            "address_id" : ObjectId("5a82f0e51139b572569fa78d"),
            "address" : "mohali ",
            "pincode" : "152364",
            "country" : "India"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `$elemMAtch`, just a condition for the sub-documents within array. In your case:

```
db.add_fun.update(
{},
{ $pull: {
    address: {
        pincode: "140901"
    }    
} },
{ multi:true }
);
```

Docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: Not working error "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"

Comment: What you expect it to do with documents where address is not an array?

Comment: I want to remove all this  {
            "address_id" : ObjectId("5a82f0e51139b572569fa78c"),
            "address" : "Mullanpur ",
            "pincode" : "140901",
            "country" : "India"
        },  where pincode is 140901

Comment: You have documents where address is not an array at all.

Comment: then how can do this?

Comment: after run a query result will display like this: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a82e6dc1139b572569fa785"),
    "name" : "Vikas",
    "salary" : 72.0,
    "address" : [ 
        
        {
            "address_id" : ObjectId("5a82f0e51139b572569fa78d"),
            "address" : "mohali ",
            "pincode" : "152364",
            "country" : "India"
        }
    ]
}   remove one address

Comment: And please let me know why address is not an array ?

Comment: it is working here:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/  In this example " Remove Items from an Array of Documents "  but not on my records why?

Comment: Your collection have at least 1 document with different structure, where address either does not exist or is not an array

Comment: so no solution?

Comment: Man, there are number of solutions, depending on what you need it to do with such documents. Answers my question and I will update my answers.

Comment: Sir I have updated my question please check it and let me know how can I help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165128/discussion-between-alex-blex-and-jaskaran-singh-rajal).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a query on the address field to make sure you're only updating arrays:

```
db.add_fun.update(
    { address: { $type: 4 }},
    { $pull: {
        address: {
            pincode: "140901"
        }    
     } },
    { multi:true }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, let me recommend you remove objects by ObjectId to guarantee uniqueness.

```
db.add_fun.update(
    { },
    { $pull: {
        address: {
            "address_id" : ObjectId("5a82f0e51139b572569fa78c")
        }    
     } },
    { multi:true }
);
```